# Why does dirty water come into my second sink when the garbage disposal is on?

Tags: sink, drain, garbage-disposal

For a while I have been having problems with using the garbage disposal.  The large sink empties very slowly and sometimes I put the disposal on to get it going.  The only problem is that disgusting dirty water comes up the drain in the small sink.

Why is this and how do I fix the problem?

Comment: Has this been an ongoing problem or has just started recently?

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like the drain after the disposal and connection to the other sink is partially blocked. I'd start with a drain cleaner that's designed for a partial blockage. In the kitchen, it's likely a buildup from cooking oils and grease that got into the drain. If that doesn't work, then you can remove the trap under your sink and remove as much crud from it as you can get. Note that the trap will be full of dirty water, so have a bucket under it when you remove it. If it's still giving you trouble, snake the line after the trap.